# Let $k,j \in \mathbb N_{\geqslant 3}$ such that $k \neq j$. Is it true that $|2^{-k} -2^{-j}| \geqslant 8^{-k} + 8^{-j}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, solution-verification

**Question.** Consider arbitrary distinct elements $k,j \in \mathbb N_{\geqslant 3}$, i.e., $k,j$ are two distinct integers greater or equal than $3$. I am wondering if the inequality

$$ |2^{-k} - 2^{-j} |\geqslant 8^{-k} + 8^{-j} $$

is satisfied.

**My attempt.** For simplicity, I started by considering the case $j > k$. With this in mind, it is clear that

$$ |2^{-k} - 2^{-j}| = 2^{-k} - 2^{-j}. $$

But now I don't know how to proceed. I have tried using the decomposition $8 = 2^3$ which yields the inequality

$$ 2^{-k} - 2^{-j} \geqslant 2^{-3k} + 2^{-3j} $$

but I also don't know how to check if this is true. Does anyone have an idea on how to prove this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k<j$ then
$$2^{-k}-2^{-j}=2^{-k}(1-2^{k-j})\ge 2^{-k}(1-2^{-1})=2^{-k-1}$$
On the other hand
$$8^{-k}+8^{-j}\le 8^{-k}+8^{-k-1}=9\cdot8^{-k-1}$$
So it suffices to show that
$2^{-k-1}> 9\cdot 8^{-k-1}$ which is equivalent to
$4^{k+1}> 9. $ The latter holds if $k\ge 1.$